# Prop to Class Variable Destructuring in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Is there a way to break down a prop object and assign them to a variable of the same name in the class?

I know about

```
({ first: this.first, second: this.second, } = props)
```

but you still have to specify what goes where. This gets messy with many variables.

I tried using

```
Object.assign(this, props);
```

but can't get it to work in the way I described.

I just think that doing something like:

```
this.first = props.first;
this.second = props.second;
...
```

is very cumbersome.

Comment: *"I tried using `Object.assign(this, props);` but can't get it to work in the way I described."* is how you'd do it, if you want **all** of the props assigned as properties. What did it do / no do that you didn't expect / expected?

Comment: Is this ok for you: `Object.entries(this.props).forEach(([key, value]) => this[key] = value)`

Comment: @Kornflexx - That's basically what `Object.assign(this, props);` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, your `Object.assign(this, props);` is about as automatic as it gets in JavaScript (and even in TypeScript; for now, you can't use destructuring with automatic initialization).

Mostly you don't want to do that with props anyway, see under the line below, but sticking to the question asked:

You could use an array with the names of the props, probably with a reusable utility function, for instance:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    grab(["first", "second"], this, props);
}
```

where `grab` is

```
function grab(names, target, source) {
    for (const name of names) {
        target[name] = source[name];
    }
    return target;
}
```

But mixing string literals with property literals like that can give you a bit of hassle when using refactoring tools that might miss them.

---

**However**, assigning props to instance properties is fairly unusual vs. simply using them from `this.props` (which is set up by `React.Component`'s constructor), perhaps via destructuring in the method where you want to use them:

```
render() {
    const {first, second} = this.props;
    return /*... JSX using `first` and `second` ... */;
}
```

Comment: Would spread operator help in making it more readable against `Object.assign`? let newProp = {...this.props}. But I do agree with the above answer on the notion of having to make a copy of props is unusual.

Comment: @Zer0 - Spread syntax *(not an operator ;-) )* wouldn't help. That example would just create a new object with a shallow copy of `props`. You'd want something like the [pick notation](https://github.com/rtm/js-pick-notation) Bob Myers suggested a long time back but which never got picked up by TC39 (sadly, in my view).

Comment: Well I mainly use those types of classes to transport data, ex: fetching from a database and dispersing the object that encapsulates the data to different places. Is that not the best way to do it?

Comment: @Questioneering - It's hard to say from such a brief description, but if it's a component that does some work based on props and renders other components, that's fine; but you typically wouldn't grab those props to instance properties on the component, you'd just use them from `this.props` (directly, or more often in my experience, via destructuring).